# The "too short" comment error is absent on mobile web

Tags: discussion, comments, mobile-web

When I'm in the full site and attempt to leave a comment containing fewer than N characters, I get an "N to go..." message.

On mobile web, the comment only fails to submit. No errors or any hints. I propose that the user be somehow alerted on mobile web when a comment is too short.